# Why does numpy let you add different size arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why doesn't numpy throw an error when you do something like

```
np.ones((5,5)) + np.ones(5)
```

Such addition is not clearly defined in linear algebra, and it just took me several hours to track down a bug that boiled down to this

Comment: [see NumPy broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: Such feature (smart array addition) is very useful in programming... and it was implemented in numpy. Dont be surprised, but 'a'+'b'='ab', and 'a'*3='aaa' -  these feature are convinient too...

Comment: throwing an exception is also not defined in linear algebra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
np.ones((5,5)) + np.ones(5)
np.ones((5,5)) + np.ones(4) <- This would give a error.
```

since np.ones(5) fit the size of each row it will to a element wise addition to each row.

That's simply how numpy works. I's is not a linear algebra module.

Here is a short example of how you could do it, this does need to be extended, with more logic and cleverness. Just a proof of concept.

```
import numpy as np

class myMatrixClass(np.ndarray):
    def __add__(self,val):
        if (hasattr(val, '__iter__') and self.shape != val.shape):
            print "not valid addition!"
        else:
            return super(myMatrixClass, self).__add__(val)

In [33]: A = myMatrixClass( shape=(5,5))

In [34]: A[:] = 1

In [35]: B = A + 1

In [36]: B
Out[36]:
myMatrixClass([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])

In [37]: C = A + np.ones(5)
not valid addition!
```

Comment: a good way to visualize the element-wise addition is doing: `np.ones((5,5)) + np.arange(5)`

Comment: It is also very handy, say when you have a 3xN array and want to remove the mean (a 3x1 vector) from each row.

Comment: If you wanted the error to be thrown, you would probably have to subclass the numpy array, and redefine all the operator functions with size checking, in the end calling the original operator functions if they pass the test

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because **numpy** broadcasts smaller arrays to fit the shape of the larger array. See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

This may not necessary coincide with "normal linear algebra" however.

it is very well exaplined in the above doc:

```
a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
b = 2.0
a * b
```

Results in:

```
array([ 2.,  4.,  6.])
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to say with your last example. Multiplying a vector with a scalar is of course perfectly valid in linear algebra.

Comment: Of course it is! The example from straight from the numpy docs :)

Comment: Ok, looked at it. While true, it's not really the most informative example of the numpy broadcasting rules :P

Comment: Not, but the rest of the doc(s) are/is :) No sense in duplicating much more of the docs! RTFD :)